# Using result value from FileReader outside of jQuery window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the result value from a FileReader call outside of its jQuery window.

```
<body>
<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename">
<script>
    $("#filename").change(function(e) {
        var ext = $("input#filename").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase(),
            reader = new FileReader(e.target.result);
        reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
    });
    //I want to use the result here
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Create a handler function, then pass `e.target.files` to it

Comment: @AdamAzad What would that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#filename").change(function(e) {
    var ext = $("input#filename").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase(),
        reader = new FileReader(e.target.result);
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
    fileHandler(reader);
});
function fileHandler(files) {
    console.log(files);
    // code
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename">
```

Comment: The code needs a change, `fileHandler(e.target.file);` to `fileHandler(reader);`